# .Net Core Cookie Authentication - User Getting Wrong Claims

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-authorization, core-authentication

I have a very strange issue with a .net core mvc site, which is hosted in IIS.

When a user logs in with this code:

```
var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                     new List<Claim>() { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin", null), new Claim("Name", userName, null) }, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

                    var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        AllowRefresh = true,
                        ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30),
                        IsPersistent = false,
                    };

                    HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                        new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                        authProperties);
```

The first user logs in with their name being displayed.  However, when another user logs on they get the first users name displayed rather than their own.

I have tried experimenting with the cookie options all with no success but this is my current configuration:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
         .AddCookie(options => {
             options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
             options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
             options.LogoutPath = "/Account/LogOff";
             options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
             options.Cookie.MaxAge = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0, 0, 0);
             options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
             options.Cookie.Name = "SITECODEHERE";
         });
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I am sure that I am making a silly mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

After much investigating it turns out that issue was being caused by caching on our firewall.

Removing this solved the issue.